How can I add custom xtics for a python gnuplotlib plot?
I want to add custom tick labels on the x-axis using the python gnuplotlib.
I have tried (using jupyterlab):
import numpy as np
import gnuplotlib as gp

xtics_positions = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
xtics_labels = ["zero", "two", "four", "six", "eight"]
xtics = [(label, pos) for label, pos in zip(xtics_labels, xtics_positions)]

datapoints = np.array([ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11,  5,  5,  2, 21,  1, 21,  0,  8, 62, 56,  0,  0,  0,  6,  3, 32,  7, 17,  1,  6, 10, 12,  0, 21, 11,  6, 14,  1, 15, 25, 30, 17, 11,  6,  4,  0])
gp.plot(datapoints, xtics = xtics)

but that does not work.
If I call gp.plot(datapoints), the plot produced is:


did you run code in console to see error messages? it gives me error message gnuplotlib.GnuplotlibError: Option 'xtics' not not known in any '['curve', 'subplot', 'process']' options sets

it seems there is other module pygnuplot  which uses plot(... xtics=...). For gnuplotlib works for me something like plot(..., set=["xtics 5,10,30"]) (Based on xtics)

First: when I run your code in console then I see error message
gnuplotlib.GnuplotlibError: 
Option 'xtics' not not known in any '['curve', 'subplot', 'process']' options sets

I found that there is other module py-gnuplot which uses xtics=...
but module gnuplotlib needs set=['xtics ...']
gp.plot(..., set=['xtics ("five" 5,"ten" 10,"more" 30)'])



xtics_strings = [f'"{label}" {pos}' for label, pos in zip(xtics_labels, xtics_positions)]
text = 'xtics (' + ','.join(xtics_strings) + ')'

gp.plot(datapoints, set=[text])


Full code:
import numpy as np
import gnuplotlib as gp

xtics_positions = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
xtics_labels = ["zero", "two", "four", "six", "eight"]
xtics = [(label, pos) for label, pos in zip(xtics_labels, xtics_positions)]

datapoints = np.array([ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11,  5,  5,  2, 21,  1, 21,  0,  8, 62, 56,  0,  0,  0,  6,  3, 32,  7, 17,  1,  6, 10, 12,  0, 21, 11,  6, 14,  1, 15, 25, 30, 17, 11,  6,  4,  0])

#gp.plot(datapoints, set=['xtics ("five" 5,"ten" 10,"more" 30)']

xtics_strings = [f'"{label}" {pos}' for label, pos in zip(xtics_labels, xtics_positions)]
text = 'xtics (' + ','.join(xtics_strings) + ')'

gp.plot(datapoints, set=[text])


Custom xtics in gnuplot - Stack Overflow
Gnuplotlib source code: set/unset
Gnuplot doc: xtics (see | ({"<label>"} <pos> {<level>} {,{"<label>"}...) })
